# Query runs successfully and fetches empty result from user defined bucket, scope, and collection

Tags: indexing, collections, couchbase, bucket, sql++

I have set up a local couchbase one node cluster environment on Ubuntu.

Query runs and fetches result from default bucket after importing all the JSON documents in zip folder using cbdoclcoader command to default bucket

Command:

/opt/couchbase/bin/cbdocloader -c localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p 10i-0113 -b mybucket -m 100 -d Downloads/JSONs_List20211229-20220123T140145Z-001.zip

Query runs and fetches empty result from user defined bucket, scope, and collection and I don't find the reason of this although i have successfully imported json documents using the below command

/opt/couchbase/bin/cbimport json -c localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p 10i-0113 -b One_bucket -f lines -d file://'fileset__e53c883b-bc30-42cb-b4f7-969998c91e3d.json' -t 2 -g %type%::%id% --scope-collection-exp Raw.%type%

My guess is that when I try to create the index, it creates an index on the default bucket and I can not find a way to create an index on my custom bucket.

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it :). Yes I was not getting any results when I try to query the collection because there was no index created on it.

Creating the index fixed the issue.

CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON default:`onebucket`.rawscope.fileset